# Best way to organize your localized translation file

Tags: php, localization, translation, gettext

As I've started building a project, there will be quite a few entries in the .po translation file. I use Poedit to build these.

My question is, what is the best practice for entries within this file? I was thinking, instead of referencing entries such as:

```
echo _('This is an entry.');
```

I was thinking of organizing them like:

```
echo _('error_pwd');
echo _('error_user_taken');
```

Which, once ran through the translation file, would output something like:

```
Password incorrect. Please try again.
Username is already taken. Please try another.
```

So, all my translations can be organized by type, such as `error_`, `msg_`, `status_`, `tip_`, etc.

Has anyone seen it done this way, or have any suggestions on a more organized method?

Comment: Yes - multiple translation files for each type. Other translation libraries support this such as Symfony2, but I don't know about your implementation.

Comment: Second is better, maybe you want to change English errors at a later point too, if you use the first and then change English messages, it will cause possible mistakes

Comment: I dont understand, i just noticed the date of question which is `asked Apr 28 at 20:29`, and no bounty is set, why are we seeing this in the first page now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it doesn't matter!

It's just up to you.

However, I advise you do not split translations in sections. 
No there's any benefit in doing so. Actually, the most projects use the one file approach for all msgid entries.
Like django, [see](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/locale).

Of course, If you still want split translation by sections, might you want take a look on [Domains](http://php.net/manual/en/function.textdomain.php):

**From PHP doc:**

> This function (textdomain()) sets the domain to search within when calls are made to
>   gettext(), usually the named after an application.

Also, as earlier said, the advantage when using `msgid` as a real phrase ou word (instead underline or dotted notation key) is that it stays as default message if no there's a translation for entry.

And here goes some helpful links:

- [Django Porject - i18n, Definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/#definitions)
- [PHP textdomain function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.textdomain.php)
- [What is bindtextdomain, textdomain in gettext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989086/what-is-bindtextdomain-textdomain-in-gettext)
- [How to determine which catalog to be used](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locating-gettext-catalog.html#Locating-gettext-catalog)

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard approach for other framework, e.g. Symfony/Laravel:

```
trans('error.validation');
```

But it has a downfall, if you forget to translate one phrase on your site it will appear like the keyword 'error.validation'

Comment: Why not check and if the phrase is not found just show the message 'Error'